# Como obtener la ruta del archivo JS correctamente cuando esta en el servidor IIS? .NET

Tags: javascript, css, asp.net-mvc, iis, fullcalendar

Estoy tratando de obtener la ruta en donde se encuentra el archivo JS en el servidor, ya que al estar probando en mi maquina localmente si obtiene la ruta del archivo pero cuando lo subo al servidor me forma la ruta incompleta, me podrían apoyar en esta situación?

Este es el mensaje que marca:

> Agenda:337 GET http://srv-webtest/Andres/vendors/FULLCALENDAR-4-1-0-DESCARGA/Core/main.min.js net::ERR_ABORTED 404 (Not Found)
> le falta una carpeta :**citassedue**

La ruta deberia ser la siguiente:

> http://srv-webtest/Andres/citassedue/vendors/FULLCALENDAR-4-1-0-DESCARGA/Core/main.min.js

Asi lo tengo en el Codigo:

```
<script src="~/../vendors/FULLCALENDAR-4-1-0-DESCARGA/Core/main.min.js"></script>
```

Saludos.

Comment: Quizas que no entendí bien lo que estas expresando pero intentaste agregar la carpeta **citassedue** a la ruta del script?

`<script src="~/../citassedue/vendors/FULLCALENDAR-4-1-0-DESCARGA/Core/main.min.js"></script>`

Answer (score 0):

Con `loc.pathname`, te funcionará emulando en `Visual Studio`, como si lo añades al servidor y tiene un nombre de instancia.

`Tabla_imagenes` es un contenedor donde inserto la imagen

```
var loc = window.location;
//loc.pathname

var container = document.getElementById('Tabla_imagenes');
// Inserta la imagen en el elemento
container.innerHTML = "<img src=./" + loc.pathname +/Imagenes/noexistecaptura.jpg width= '480' height= '320' />";

document.getElementById("preloader").style.display = "none";
```